# How can I use read on a string that is not double quoted?

Tags: string, parsing, haskell, io

I'm reading values from in from a console using `readLn`.

I'd like to write a function:

```
requestValue :: String -> IO a  
requestValue s = do  
  putStrLn $ "Please enter a new value for " ++ s   
  readLn
```

I'd then be able to do, for example,

```
changeAge :: Person -> IO Person
changeAge p = do
    age' <- requestValue "age"
    return $ p { age = age'}

changeName :: Person -> IO Person
changeName p = do
    name' <- requestValue "name"
    return $ p { name = name'}
```

The problem I have is that the read instance of String seems to require the string to be in quotes. I don't want to have to enter `"Fred"` in the console to change name when I really only want to type in `Fred`.

Is there an easy way to do this that keeps `requestValue` polymorphic?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since you want to add your own custom `read` behavior for user names, the way to do that is to actually write a new instance for readings names. To do *that* we can create a new type for names:

```
import Control.Arrow (first)

newtype Name = Name { unName :: String }
    deriving (Eq, Ord, Show)
```

and write a custom `read` for it:

```
instance Read Name where
    readsPrec n = map (first Name) . readsPrec n . quote
        where quote s = '"' : s ++ ['"']
```

this is the same as the read instance for strings, but we first quote the string, *after* reading it in.

Now you can modify your `Person` type to use `Name` instead of `String`:

```
data Person = Person { age :: Int
                     , name :: Name } deriving Show
```

and we're in business:

```
*Main> changeName (Person 31 (Name "dons"))
Please enter a new value for name
Don
Person {age = 31, name = Name {unName = "Don"}}
```

Comment: Shouldn't you also take care to escape the quoted string?

Answer (score 2):

You want `getLine`, not `readLn`.

Comment: No I don't. getLine is of type `IO String` whereas readLn is `IO a`. I want requestValue to be of type `String -> IO a`, so I need readLn, not getLine.

Comment: Yeah, look at Don's answer instead. :)